# Java dot doesn't match 'any character'

Tags: java, regex, string, url, replace

Dot should match any character. So why doesn't this regex work?

```
String url = "http://wikipedia.org";
System.out.println(url.replace("htt.://", ""));
```

Output: `http://wikipedia.org`

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Don't use regex for that, use [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) compiles a **literal regex**. You ought to use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or [`String.replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String url = "http://wikipedia.org";
System.out.println(url.replaceFirst("htt.://", ""));
```

Here is from the Java source code, the method `.replace()`:

```
/**
 * Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
 * sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
 * replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
 * example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
 * "ba" rather than "ab".
 *
 * @param  target The sequence of char values to be replaced
 * @param  replacement The replacement sequence of char values
 * @return  The resulting string
 * @throws NullPointerException if <code>target</code> or
 *         <code>replacement</code> is <code>null</code>.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if the term 'literal regex' is correct here.

Comment: @Unihedron That is an implementation detail that is *not* in the documentation of [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 7):

You are using `replace()` method. It takes a String not a regex
You can use `replaceAll();` which takes a regex like this : `replaceAll("htt.://", "");`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which will interpret the first parameter as a regex.

```
String url = "http://wikipedia.org";
System.out.println(url.replaceAll("htt.://", ""));
```

Outputs

> wikipedia.org

One remark though: I assume you are trying to make both `http` and `https` work with your regex. The way you have it right now won't work because it will expect only 1 character and not 2 in the case of "https". In order to make up for this, use

```
url.replaceAll("htt.*://", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()` function instead of the `replace()` to make use of regexes:

```
String url = "http://wikipedia.org";
System.out.println(url.replaceAll("htt.://", ""));
```