# Replace a set of substring in a string in more efficient way?

Tags: java, regex, string

I've to replace a set of substrings in a String with another substrings for example

1. `"^t"` with `"\t"`
2. `"^="` with `"\u2014"`
3. `"^+"` with `"\u2013"`
4. `"^s"` with `"\u00A0"`
5. `"^?"` with `"."`
6. `"^#"` with `"\\d"`
7. `"^$"`  with `"[a-zA-Z]"`

So, I've tried with:

```
String oppip = "pippo^t^# p^+alt^shefhjkhfjkdgfkagfafdjgbcnbch^";

Map<String,String> tokens = new HashMap<String,String>();
tokens.put("^t", "\t");
tokens.put("^=", "\u2014");
tokens.put("^+", "\u2013");
tokens.put("^s", "\u00A0");
tokens.put("^?", ".");
tokens.put("^#", "\\d");
tokens.put("^$", "[a-zA-Z]");

String regexp = "^t|^=|^+|^s|^?|^#|^$";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(oppip);
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb, tokens.get(m.group()));
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

But it doesn't work. `tokens.get(m.group())` throws an exception.

Any idea why?

Comment: What exception does `tokens.get(m.group())` throw? Can you give the full exception stack trace?

Comment: Sorry. I've forgotten. Null pointer exception

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use a `HashMap`. Consider using simple arrays, and a **loop**:

```
String oppip = "pippo^t^# p^+alt^shefhjkhfjkdgfkagfafdjgbcnbch^";

String[] searchFor =
{"^t", "^=", "^+", "^s", "^?", "^#", "^$"},
         replacement =
{"\\t", "\\u2014", "\\u2013", "\\u00A0", ".", "\\d", "[a-zA-Z]"};

for (int i = 0; i < searchFor.length; i++)
    oppip = oppip.replace(searchFor[i], replacement[i]);

// Print the result.
System.out.println(oppip);
```

Here is an [online code demo](http://ideone.com/xvCH30).

---

For the completeness, you can use a two-dimensional array for a similar approach:

```
String oppip = "pippo^t^# p^+alt^shefhjkhfjkdgfkagfafdjgbcnbch^";

String[][] tasks =
{
    {"^t", "\\t"},
    {"^=", "\\u2014"}, 
    {"^+", "\\u2013"}, 
    {"^s", "\\u00A0"}, 
    {"^?", "."}, 
    {"^#", "\\d"}, 
    {"^$", "[a-zA-Z]"}
};

for (String[] replacement : tasks)
    oppip = oppip.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1]);

// Print the result.
System.out.println(oppip);
```

Comment: I think you mean `replaceAll(...)` not `replace(...)`, but otherwise, I like this solution.  Don't try to do all the replacements at once, do them one at a time and the code is much simpler.

Comment: @IanMcLaird `.replaceAll` takes a regex. [`.replace()` takes a string and it's literal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25365703/3622940), so no need for escaping.

Comment: @IanMcLaird `replaceAll` uses regex, while OP clearly wants to replace literals, so `replace` is better here. But there is possible problem if cyclic replacements can exist like `a->b` `b->a`. In that case by replacing all `a` with `b` then all `b` with `a` we end up with only `a`.`appendReplacement` and `appendTail` solves this problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I'd forgotten about the version of replace that takes `CharSequence`s.  I was thinking of just `char`s.

Comment: i think the Pattern and Matcher is more efficient. with your loop i 've to iterate to all the substrings also if there isn't in the string

Comment: Matt3o's approach does have the advantage of requiring only one matching pass through the original string, and only one string allocation, though.  The approach in this answer requires N matching passes, where N is the number of replacement targets.  When N is small (which it almost certainly is), this approach will be faster, but this is a "Schlemiel the Painter" algorithm.

Comment: @Unihedron approach from your answer will require iterating over entire string for each replacement, while OP code will not have to check all patterns described by regex, but will stop at first pattern it can use, so if it will find `"^t"` at position `X` it will not test if other possibilities `^=|^+|^s|^?|^#|^$` so substring at position `X` will be tested only once. At worst case it will have to test combinations up to last one `^$`. So code from your answer is same as worst scenario of OP code (it is nice because it is clean code, but efficiency lies on regex side).

Comment: @Pshemo Literal regexes (`.replace()`) has the advantage of comparing deep equals in the `char[]` represented by the `String` object. (see impl of `Pattern` in JDK 5+) While it is true that it iterates over the entire string, that is done through deep search and is still more efficient than using regex on certain scenarios, which compares left-right pointers. At the end, the efficiency still depend on the input string. Your point is notable in possibilities however, and is worth a debate on its own. My answer would only be optimal for situations where multiple sequences are expected to be.

Comment: @Unihedron I am not sure what do you mean, I am also not saying you are wrong, I'll have to take a deeper look at code but from first glance it seems that `replace` internally uses `replaceAll` (with `Pattern.LITERAL` flag on pattern and escapes replacement with `Matcher.quoteReplacement`). This means you are invoking `replaceAll` N times (for N patterns you want to replace) which internally uses approach from OP question (appendReplacement and appendTail).

Answer (score 5):

In regex the `^` means "begin-of-text" (or "not" within a character class as negation). You have to place a backslash before it, which becomes two backslashes in a java String.

```
String regexp = "\\^[t=+s?#$]";
```

I have reduced it a bit further.